# Truncate decimal numbers of floatfield always rounding down

Tags: django

I have a float field and Im trying to only show the digit in front of the decimal point

so `8.70` will display as `8`. If the value is `9.00`, it should display as `9`

When I try to use `|floatformat:"0"` `8.70` will display as `9`

How can I make sure it never rounds up?

Comment: you have to build a custom filter..

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display the integral part of it then use `{{ value|stringformat:"d" }}`. Otherwise, build a custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in template tag for what you seek.

The way I see it you have two options.

If the value won't be used anywhere else on your page, you could just change the way it's passed on to the template by changing the context dict

```
return render(request, 'templates/my_template.html', {'my_value': math.floor(my_value)})
```

Otherwise, you can build your own template tag.

```
@register.filter
def floor_floats(value):
    return math.floor(value)
```

And then use it on the template:

```
{{ value|floor_floats }}
```

Hope this helps