# python django number format

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to format these numbers. Example:

> 24.324324324324323
>
> 18.91891891891892

I want to delete the numbers behind it to be like this

> 24.3
>
> 18.9

what can use django template tags? or using some code?

Comment: If you want to round, django has the floatformat filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat). However if you wish to truncate, it looks like there is no built in options. Although this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778986/truncate-decimal-numbers-of-floatfield-always-rounding-down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Decimals format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filter tag in your template , here is an exampe:

```
value = 12.3436547654756756    

{{ value|floatformat }} =====> 12.34
```